# D3 nested select and sibling from json property of object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to add a sibling **before** a series of `div`'s that have been created on `.enter()`. So far I have:

```
const data = [
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "hierarchies": [
            {
                "name": "Alpha",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "A1"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "A2"
                    },
                ],
                "property": {
                    "name":"Sub-Alpha"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Bravo",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "B1"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "B2"
                    },
                ],
                "property": {
                    "name":"Sub-Bravo"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]

const system = d3.select('body').selectAll('div')
    .data(data)
        .enter().append('div').classed("system", true)

const hierarchy = system.selectAll('.system')
    .data(function(d) { console.log(d.hierarchies); return d.hierarchies })
        .enter().append('div').classed("hierarchy", true)

const children = hierarchy.selectAll('.hierarchy')
    .data(function(d, i) { return d.children })
        .enter().append('div').classed("child", true)
        .text(function(d, i) { return d.name })
```

This gets me the desired output of:

```
<div class="system">
  <div class="hierarchy">
    <div class="child">A1</div>
    <div class="child">A2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hierarchy">
    <div class="child">B1</div>
    <div class="child">B2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to insert a sibling of the `.child` elements that gets it's `.text()` from `hierarchies.property.name`. The expected output would be:

```
<div class="system">
  <div class="hierarchy">
    <div class="property">Sub-Alpha</div>
    <div class="child">A1</div>
    <div class="child">A2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hierarchy">
    <div class="property">Sub-Bravo</div>
    <div class="child">B1</div>
    <div class="child">B2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to insert a sibling, you can keep using the regular selections with `append`:

```
const property = hierarchy.selectAll('.property')
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d.property]
  })
  .enter().append('div').classed("property", true)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name
  })
```

Just create that selection after `const hierarchy` and before `const children`. That will give you this structure:

```
<div class="system">
    <div class="hierarchy">
        <div class="property">Sub-Alpha</div>
        <div class="child">A1</div>
        <div class="child">A2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hierarchy">
        <div class="property">Sub-Bravo</div>
        <div class="child">B1</div>
        <div class="child">B2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const data = [{
  "name": "foo",
  "hierarchies": [{
      "name": "Alpha",
      "children": [{
          "name": "A1"
        },
        {
          "name": "A2"
        },
      ],
      "property": {
        "name": "Sub-Alpha"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Bravo",
      "children": [{
          "name": "B1"
        },
        {
          "name": "B2"
        },
      ],
      "property": {
        "name": "Sub-Bravo"
      }
    }
  ]
}]

const system = d3.select('body').selectAll('div')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('div').classed("system", true)

const hierarchy = system.selectAll('.system')
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.hierarchies
  })
  .enter().append('div').classed("hierarchy", true)

const property = hierarchy.selectAll('.property')
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d.property]
  })
  .enter().append('div').classed("property", true)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name
  })

const children = hierarchy.selectAll('.hierarchy')
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.children
  })
  .enter().append('div').classed("child", true)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank again @Gerardo, that's exactly what I was after. I'll get these selects eventually!